# unity зависает Application.Quit

Tags: c#, unity3d

при вызове метода Application.Quit - зависает игра на 3-4 секунды и только потом закрывается, иногда у некоторых перезапускается. Как это исправить? Объекты UI создаются при старте игры, пробовал удалить все объекты со сцены и только потом вызвать этот метод, но все равно результат тот же... Использую 5.6.4p4. с другим проектом на этой версии все нормально работает.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, вы выполняете при закрытии какие-то тяжёлые операции, которые занимают столько времени. Сверху во вкладке Window включите отображение окна Profiler - здесь отображается нагрузка вашего приложения на ядро/видео/память и т.д. Их можно смотреть и из редактора, но в билде будет чище, т.к. процессы самого редактора будут отсутствовать.

Соберите билд с отмеченными чекбоксами Development Build и Autoconnect Profiler. При запуске приложения к нему автоматически подключиться окно Profiler. Закройте своё приложение и смотрите, что происходило в профайлере на последних секундах его жизни. Там можно увидеть пики нагрузок, сколько на какие методы тратится процессорного времени, например. Соответственно, если будет резкий скачек нагрузки вы сможете увидеть на обработку каких методов ушла эта нагрузка.

Comment: у меня зависает профайлер вместе с игрой) убрал всю логику что может нагружать, тоже самое. P.S. Такое явление не только на этом телефоне

Comment: @GR1995, видимо, всё же, не всю логику убрали. Это какое-нибудь банальное сохранение данных может быть, а может и вовсе бесконечный цикл где-нибудь. Если пустой проект у вас соберётся и будет работать с профайлером - значит проблема в логике текущего проекта